# Silverlight datagrid cell value depending on another cell value?

Tags: silverlight

I have a datagrid which is bound to a table. I have a field nemed Typ in the datagrid which is not bound to any field. I need to display "bag" or "bulk" in the Typ field depending on there is a "B" at the end of the ProductCode field.

```
<sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="77,42,91,323" Name="dgScripts" Width="577" SelectionChanged="dgScripts_SelectionChanged">
        <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>                
            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ProductCode}" Header="Prod. Code" Width="80" />
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Width="50" />
            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MedNo}" Header="Med. Code" Width="100" />
        </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
    </sdk:DataGrid>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by these steps:

1. "Type" column -> templated column
2. "Type" column binding set to ProductCode
3. Than use Image in "Type" columns template. This image source property should use binding with a valueconverter.
4. This converter should deside whether to return "bag" or "bulk" imagesource..

Comment: i am using textcolum instead of templated column 
 and is working.. thanks